# Use EventSubscriber to register Database History in mikroorm

Tags: typescript, graphql, mikro-orm

I am fairly new to the concept of LifcycleHooks and EventSubscribers. I am trying to populate a history table that records the changes done on any other table. I have been trying to use EventSubscriber for this:
The idea is that on the onFlush event trigger of my eventSubscriber, I am extracting all the changed values and fields from the changeset and creating an object of the history table and trying to persist it but I see the following error:

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason: ValidationError: You cannot call em.flush() from inside lifecycle hook handlers
```

My subscriber looks like this:

```
import { HistoryLog } from 'src/entities/history-log.entity;
export class EntityChangeSubscriber implements EventSubscriber<AnyEntity>  {

  async afterCreate(args: EventArgs<AnyEntity>): Promise<void> {
    console.log('===========1111 AfterCreateHook');
    console.log(args.entity);
  }
  async afterUpdate(args: EventArgs<AnyEntity>): Promise<void> {
    console.log('===========2222 AfterUpdateHook');
    console.log(args.entity);
  }

  async onFlush(args: FlushEventArgs): Promise<void> {
    console.log('===========3333 onFlushHook');
    console.log(args);
    const changeSets = args.uow.getChangeSets();
    const entities = changeSets.map((cs) => cs.entity);
    console.log('Affected entities', entities);
  }

  async afterFlush(args: FlushEventArgs): Promise<void> {
    console.log('===========4444 AfterFlushHook');

    const changeSets = args.uow.getChangeSets();
    console.log('change sets', changeSets);
    changeSets?.map(async (cs) => {
      if (cs.persisted) {
        console.log('print changeset');
        let nextValues = cs.payload ? cs.payload : {};
        let tableName = cs.name;
        let operation = cs.type;
        let rowId = cs.getPrimaryKey()?.toString();
        let modifiedFields = Object.keys(cs.payload);
        let previousValues = cs.originalEntity ? cs.originalEntity : {};
       for (let key in previousValues) {
          if (
            !previousValues.hasOwnProperty(key) ||
            !modifiedFields.includes(key)
          ) {
            delete previousValues[key];
          }
        }
       const historyLog=new HistoryLog({
          operation,
          tableName,
          rowId,
          previousValues,
          nextValues
        });
        console.log(historyLog);
     
        let historyLog1= await args.em.persistAndFlush(historyLog);
        console.log('historyLog1>>> ',historyLog1);
        return historyLog1;
      }
    });
 }
}
```

My `mikro-orm-postgres.config.ts` registers the subscriber and I can see changeset being loaded
`subscribers: [new EntityChangeSubscriber()]`

How can I implement this? Is there a way that I can return the results of EventSubscriber to a service class and do a persist operation there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not flush from inside any hook or event handler. Using flush events is correct, but instead of `afterFlush` you should use `onFlush` and append the newly added entities to current unit of work. That is exactly what the example in the docs shows.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/lifecycle-hooks/#using-onflush-event

If you want to issue the query in parallel (not in the same transaction), you could either fork the EM to get around the validation error, or use `em.nativeInsert()` instead of UoW to create the new record.

Comment: I don't want my first unit of work to get hindered or delayed. My idea is that the end-user does not see a delay in response and the afterFlush occurs in the background. I could resolve the issue without moving the piece of code into onFlush by doing the following:
`args.em.fork().persistAndFlush(historyLog)`
Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Yes, if you want to fire parallel query, this is correct approach. Or you could just use `em.nativeInsert()` (no fork needed then as the method does not work with identity map).

Comment: This answers my question. Although there is also a related issue that I will open separately. Thank you Martin.